# How to empty a array after it has specific number of elements?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to keep a watch on a array , and when it has 10 elements in it , I want to clear the array. I tried using proxies but I am not able to clear my array. What I am trying to achieve is that, I am trying to push some data into an array from eventlisteners , and when the array length reaches 10 I want to send the data to server and clear the array.

Comment: Can't you do this with a simple ```if``` statement? e.g. ```if (array.length > 9) { array = [] }```

Comment: Can you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Could you provide us some code? Do you want to check its size after every iteration?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is that, I am trying to push some data into an array from eventlisteners , and when the array length reaches 10 I want to send the data to server and clear the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by overriding push method of the array,

```
function getArrayWithLimitedLength(length) {
    var array = new Array();

    array.push = function () {
        if (this.length >= length) {
            this.splice(0,this.length)
        }
        return Array.prototype.push.apply(this,arguments);
    }

    return array;
}
```

Create an array with length 3

```
var array = getArrayWithLimitedLength(3);
```

once You add 4th element previous 3 elements will be removed and last element will be added as first element.

You can use `this.splice(0,this.length)`, `this.length = 0` to clear the array

or

```
while(this.length > 0) {
    this.pop();
}
```

Example:

```
array.push(1) // array-> [1]
array.push(2) // array-> [1,2]
array.push(3) // array-> [1,2,3]
array.push(4) // array-> [4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the array has 10 elements and then call a function for sending the array. Then empty the array by seting the length to zero.

```js
function sendArray(array) {
    console.log(...array);
}

var array = [];

setInterval((i => () => {
    array.push(i++);
    if (array.length === 10) {
        sendArray(array);
        array.length = 0;
    }
})(0), 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement you own `myPush` method:

```js
Array.prototype.myPush = function(element, maxLengthBeforeFlush= Infinity) {
  this.push(element);
  if (this.length > maxLengthBeforeFlush) {
    // code to send this to the server
    this.length = 0;
  }
}

var arr = [];
```

```html
<button type="button" id="pushToArr" onclick="arr.myPush('a', 5); console.log(arr);">Click to push to arr[]</button>
```

Comment: IIRC It's considered bad practice to override the prototype, as the changes will ba made to all arrays, and may induce errors. @Tenusha's method is safer, as it changes only a single array's methods.

Comment: @Seblor I'm not overriding the prototype, I'm adding a new method to Array prototype.

Comment: Sorry, bad choice of word. I meant that you are changing the prototype, which will add the method to all arrays, possibly inducing errors.  Maybe not is this case, but it should not be the go-to solution IMO.